# AVAudioPlayer doesn't play the first time

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm having a problem with playing a sound through the AVAudioPlayer when a button is pressed for the first time. When I tap it again it works fine.

Here is the code I'm using, this is being called in my viewDidLoad()

```
func loadSounds(){
    do{
        try audioPlayerL = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: startListening!)
        try audioPlayerE = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: doneListening!)
    }
    catch{

    }
    audioPlayerL.delegate = self
    audioPlayerL.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayerE.delegate = self
    audioPlayerE.prepareToPlay()
}
```

Here is the method that plays the file

```
func playSound(){
    if(startedListening == true){
        audioPlayerL.play()
    }
    else{
        audioPlayerE.play()
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no clue why it isn't playing the first time around. On the emulator it works without any problems. Running on my iPhone 6 plus it fails the first time around.

I checked and it doesn't throw an error anywhere either.

Comment: Try to workaround AVAudioSession, doth players may conflict. Try to enable session with mixing enabled before creating players. `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];`

Comment: that actually did it thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this is closed up and anyone who has the same problem knows this was solved. Like Markov said it was fixed by adding this line of code

`try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers)`

The total looks like this

piece of code that loads the sounds

```
func loadSounds(){
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers)
        try audioPlayerL = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: startListening!)
        try audioPlayerE = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: doneListening!)
    }
    catch{
        print("error")
    }
    audioPlayerL.delegate = self
    audioPlayerL.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayerE.delegate = self
    audioPlayerE.prepareToPlay()
}
```

method that is being called to play the sounds

```
func playSound(){
    if(startedListening == true){
        audioPlayerL.play()
    }
    else{
        audioPlayerE.play()
    }
}
```